# How to fix my header getting cut off on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with fixing my header I can not find the problem! At the beginning it looks fine but when you scroll down it cuts part of it off. But when you scroll back up it goes normal. I think it is with the hamburger menu because when you click on it, it increases the cut off. Here is the link to the website. https://perfectparadox8400.000webhostapp.com/ and here is a gif of what happens!

[Link  to the picture of what happens!](https://perfectparadox8400.000webhostapp.com/vid/Screen%20recording%202021-03-04%208.27.35%20AM.gif)

I only happens when you are on a phone. I used the inspector tools to test it and I did try it on a phone to.

Here is the header code.

```
<header id="headerrr" class="fixed-top lode">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="lode" class="logo float-center">
        <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
        <!-- <h1 class="text-light"><a href="#header"><span>NewBiz</span></a></h1> -->
        <a href="#intro">
                <img id="headerr" class="bigg" src="img/l.png" heigth="100%"><div id="lod" class="lod" style=display:inline-block;vertical-align:center>&nbsp;Perfect Paradox's 8400</div></a>
      <div id="dlod" class="loder">
          <div class="fixx">
          <div class="float-center lodbar">Loding...
          <div id="barr" class="persent">&nbsp;</div>
             </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script>
      var w = 5;
var foo = setInterval(function () {
    if(w>109) {cancelInterval(foo)}
    w = w + 6.25;
    document.getElementById('barr').style.width = w + '%';
}, 1000);
      </script>
      <nav id="lood" class="lod main-nav float-right d-none d-lg-block header">
        <ul>
          <li class="drop-down"><a>Home</a>
          <ul>
          <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
            </ul> 
          </li>
          <li class="drop-down" ><a>FTC</a>
          <ul>
               <li><a href="/">FTC Page</a></li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="https://www.firstinspires.org/community/">FTC At Home</a>
                      </li>
                  <li><a href="https://www.firstinspires.org/robotics/ftc">About FTC</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/">FLL</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Junior FLL</a></li> 
          <li class="drop-down"><a>More</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://perfectparadox8400.wixsite.com/mysite">Old Website</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/">FLL</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Junior FLL</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav><!-- .main-nav -->
    </div>
  </header><!-- #header -->
```

The css.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
    .lode {
        height: 100% !important;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .lod {
        display: none !important;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .bigg {
        margin-left: 25% !important;
        margin-right: 25% !important;
       width: 50% !important;
       -webkit-animation-name:            rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration:        3s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .float-center {
       margin-top: 8% !important;
       transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .loder {
        width: 80%;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .fixx {
        position: relative;
    }
    .lodbar {
        width: 125%;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        background-color: #afb0b3;
        height: 0.5%;
    }
    .persent {
        width: 0%;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        background-color: #5e068a;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 0;
    }
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#headerrr {
  height: 80px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  padding: 0px 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.header {
  height: 80px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: transparent !important;
}
#headerrr.header-scrolledd {
  height: 60px;   
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#headerr.header-scrolleddd {
  width: 76px;   
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#headerr {
  width: 100px;   
  transition: all 0.5s;  
}
.header.header-scrolled,
.header.header-pages {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#headerrr .logo h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#headerrr .logo h1 a {
    margin: 7px 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#headerrr .logo h1 a:hover {
  color: #5e068a;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#headerrr .logo img{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

The javascript.

```
(function ($) {
  "use strict";

  // Preloader (if the #preloader div exists)
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    if ($('#preloader').length) {
      $('#preloader').delay(100).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  });

  // Back to top button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });
  $('.back-to-top').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    return false;
  });

  // Initiate the wowjs animation library
  new WOW().init();

  // Header scroll class
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.header').addClass('header-scrolled');
      $('#headerrr').addClass('header-scrolledd');
      $('#headerr').addClass('header-scrolleddd');
    } else {
      $('.header').removeClass('header-scrolled');
      $('#headerrr').removeClass('header-scrolledd');
      $('#headerr').removeClass('header-scrolleddd');
    }
  });

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.header').addClass('header-scrolled');
    $('#headerrr').addClass('header-scrolledd');
    $('#headerr').addClass('header-scrolleddd');
  }

  // Smooth scroll for the navigation and links with .scrollto classes
  $('.main-nav a, .mobile-nav a, .scrollto').on('click', function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      if (target.length) {
        var top_space = 0;

        if ($('#headerrr').length) {
          top_space = $('#headerrr').outerHeight();

          if (! $('#headerrr').hasClass('header-scrolledd')) {
            top_space = top_space - 0;
          }
        }

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - top_space
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

        if ($(this).parents('.main-nav, .mobile-nav').length) {
          $('.main-nav .active, .mobile-nav .active').removeClass('active');
          $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }

        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
          $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
          $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('fa-times fa-bars');
          $('.mobile-nav-overly').fadeOut();
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  // Navigation active state on scroll
  var nav_sections = $('section');
  var main_nav = $('.main-nav, .mobile-nav');
  var main_nav_height = $('#headerrr').outerHeight();

  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
  
    nav_sections.each(function() {
      var top = $(this).offset().top - main_nav_height,
          bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
  
      if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
        main_nav.find('li').removeClass('active');
        main_nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
      }
    });
  });

  // jQuery counterUp (used in Whu Us section)
  $('[data-toggle="counter-up"]').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 1000
  });

  // Porfolio isotope and filter
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    var portfolioIsotope = $('.portfolio-container').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
    });
    $('#portfolio-flters li').on( 'click', function() {
      $("#portfolio-flters li").removeClass('filter-active');
      $(this).addClass('filter-active');
  
      portfolioIsotope.isotope({ filter: $(this).data('filter') });
    });
  });

  // Testimonials carousel (uses the Owl Carousel library)
  $(".testimonials-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    loop: true,
    items: 1,
    delay: 100
  });

})(jQuery);
```

These are the parts with the header involved!
Please help!
I tried removing the javascript but it did not help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this: `html, body {width: auto!important; overflow-x: hidden!important}` and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You adding the `on scroll shrink` effect to the header

There is two ways to solve this

1. removing `header-scrolled` css or change the `height` of header-scrolled to according to main height mentioned in `headerrr` css

   ```
    #headerrr.header-scrolledd {
       height: 60px;   
      transition: all 0.5s;
     }
   ```

The main height of the header is `80px` you adding the `header-scrolled`css onscroll in javascript  the `header-scrolled` height of is `66px` 
 so when you scroll down the screen get shrink 
 so change the `height` of `header-scrolled` to `80px` to avoid shrink

second way is to remove the javascript for header

```
// Header scroll class
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
   $('.header').addClass('header-scrolled');
   $('#headerrr').addClass('header-scrolledd');
   $('#headerr').addClass('header-scrolleddd');
 } else {
   $('.header').removeClass('header-scrolled');
   $('#headerrr').removeClass('header-scrolledd');
   $('#headerr').removeClass('header-scrolleddd');
 }
});

if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
 $('.header').addClass('header-scrolled');
 $('#headerrr').addClass('header-scrolledd');
 $('#headerr').addClass('header-scrolleddd');
}
```

remove this code block it will remove the onscroll function for header removig this will leads to your header will not shrink on scroll

you can choose any one way
my suggestion to remove both `header-scrolled` and javascript code

Comment: How could I remove the shrink affect only on mobile phones?

Comment: with `media-queries` add `height:80px` to `header-scrolled`

Comment: Look at the picture of what happens I don't think it is not the shrinking problem.

Comment: Why is the hamburger menu make the cut of worse.

Comment: Why is the `header-scrolled height is 66px`

Comment: on scroll is only causing the cutoff try with removing  on scroll function  the code  `header-scrolled` height 60 is for shrink the header from 80 to 60 so try

Comment: look at it now it still cuts it off I removed the javascript.

Comment: Do you see what I mean?

Comment: There is position at the bottom could that be it?

Comment: The header is bigger than 100%

Comment: Thank you for your help! You got me on the right track!